# Implementing execvp() using execv()

Tags: c, process, char, arguments, constants

I'm trying to implement `execvp()` using the call of `execv()`. What I know at the moment about those functions is that one uses path to file, the other uses only the filename.

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

How can I actually do that using both functions ? Extract somehow from path-to-file of `execv` the filename or is there a way more simple method to do that I can't think of?

Comment: https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/blob/master/posix/execvp.c#L50 `How can I actually do that using both functions ?` Do what exactly? You want to implement `execv` using `execv`?

Comment: @KamilCuk to have `execvp` using `execv`